# New tag: therapeutic-diet

Tags: discussion, tags, announcement

I created this new tag: [therapeutic-diet](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/therapeutic-diet)

This tag is for questions about eating patterns that aim to assist with recovery or mitigation of chronic disease or other conditions. I'm surprised that I only found a few questions on this subject, as I expected more based on how many people take interest in a vegan diet (especially a whole food plant-based diet) after their health takes a turn for the worse.

- [Can going vegan have additional benefits for people with Ehlers Danlos Syndrome](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/1786/can-going-vegan-have-additional-benefits-for-people-with-ehlers-danlos-syndrome)
- [Diabetes and vegan diet to control blood sugar](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/1675/diabetes-and-vegan-diet-to-control-blood-sugar)
- [Does a vegan diet help to reduce allergy symptoms?](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/650/does-a-vegan-diet-help-to-reduce-allergy-symptoms)
- [Can vegan diets have a positive effect on people with diabetes?](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/278/can-vegan-diets-have-a-positive-effect-on-people-with-diabetes)
- [Is there any evidence that vegan and/or rawfood diets are beneficial to people that suffer from rheumatoid arthritis?](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/315/is-there-any-evidence-that-vegan-and-or-rawfood-diets-are-beneficial-to-people-t)